# "Connection Partially Encrypted" in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox, ssl

I can't figure out if this is a bug in Firefox or an anomaly with the website as it only seems to occur through a specific sequence.

*TLDR steps below*

If you visit the main page (link below) and then click on the quotes link it will send you to a page called quoteconfig.aspx which checks for javascript and then redirects you if it's enabled otherwise it gives you a warning. After the automatic redirect Firefox shows a SSL warning about "Connection Partially Encrypted" (see the icon on the statusbar). However, if you click the sign in or my account links, which do not perform a javascript redirect, there's no SSL warning. Also, upon refreshing the page or browsing to another page then clicking the quotes links again the SSL warning goes away.

I've run Fiddler and Windows Network Monitor and verified that all links on the page are https://. It works fine on IE 7&8, Safari, Opera, and Chrome.

What else could it be?

steps:

1. visit the url below using Firefox
   (tested on 3.0.5)
2. click on the quotes link
3. observe the SSL warning in the
   statusbar

[site link](http://www.zoomrp.com)

Comment: I don't get any warnings in Firefox 3 on Mac. Just letting you know. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `window.location = "quote.aspx"` might be the culprit. On my browser, at least, it is redirecting to the http version of the page, not https. Then the http redirects to the https straight away with a 302.

Comment: I tried window.location = "https://" + window.location.host + "/quote.aspx"; but still get the SSL warning in Firefox.

Comment: So you comment that this wasn't the fix, and then you accept it as the solution? What the hell?